# Average of last 6 elements from given element in list

Tags: python, list, pandas, deque

I have `list=[307, 258, 164, 193, 174, 285, 230, 160, 257, 306, 173, 169, 192, 209, 110]`

I want to calculate average last 6 elements from given element[n] in list and after that `n` should iterate by 1[n+1] and again same operation should perform.

L3[-15:] I know how to access last few elements from d list.
`new_list = my_list[(len(my_list) - 10):]` .How can I use a deque for this

Please help, thanks

Comment: Why would you use a deque for this if you already have a list and you're not adding or removing anything?

Comment: No I'm not deleting . how it can be done by llist then?

Comment: `sum(lst[-6:])/6`? I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: I mean suppose I have 8th element from the list then it will then take avg of last 6 elemnts from that element in the list & iterate (8+1) and again find the avg of last 6 ele.

Comment: Right, so [`pandas.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)? To my knowledge, a deque is irrelevant to pandas but I've just seen that you've tagged it with pandas. It's very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: how can i use that here?

Comment: also, please do not use `list` as a variable name since `list` is a built-in Python type.

Comment: I think you're better using the answer given by Julien Spronck which uses neither pandas nor a deque until you have a better understanding of what both of those do. As far as I can tell, it gives your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand what you're asking but maybe you're looking for a rolling average. In this case, I'm using a list comprehension to create the rolling average:

```
mylist = [307, 258, 164, 193, 174, 285, 230, 160, 257, 306, 173, 169, 192, 209, 110]
rolling_avg = [mylist[j-6:j]/6 for j in range(6, len(mylist))]
# [230.16666666666666,
#  217.33333333333334,
#  201.0,
#  216.5,
#  235.33333333333334,
#  235.16666666666666,
#  215.83333333333334,
#  209.5,
#  217.66666666666666]
```

where the first number in `rolling_avg` is the average of the six first numbers in `mylist`, the second number is the average of the numbers at indices 1 to 6, ...

Answer (score 2):

I think better is use [Julien Spronck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51075549/2901002) solution, but if want use pandas solution is [`rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `mean`:

```
out = pd.Series(mylist).rolling(6).mean().dropna().tolist()
print (out)

[230.16666666666666, 217.33333333333334, 
 201.0, 216.5, 
 235.33333333333334, 235.16666666666666, 
 215.83333333333334, 209.5, 
 217.66666666666666, 193.16666666666666]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `collections.deque` for this, to hold only 6 elements at the time and finding the average of the deque

```
from collections import deque
lst = [307, 258, 164, 193, 174, 285, 230, 160, 257, 306, 173, 169, 192, 209, 110]
n = 6
d = deque(maxlen=n)

[d.append(e) or sum(d)/float(n) for e in lst][n-1:]
# [230.16666666666666, 217.33333333333334, 201.0, 216.5, 235.33333333333334, 235.16666666666666, 215.83333333333334, 209.5, 217.66666666666666, 193.16666666666666]
```

Comment: yes all the solutions are working .thank you so much